# SQL get all the columns form a user that has at least 2 vowels in the column name and also its length is superior to 8 in ORACLE DBMS

Tags: sql, oracle

for this assignment I have to return the names of the columns in all tables from a specific user where the column name has at least 2 vowels and the its length is superior to 8. I know that sql can handle regular expression unfortunately I don't know if it can be used in this case.

Here is a practical example of what I want my request to do.

## Here is the existing tables and columns

| Table name | Column name |
| --- | --- |
| Person | identification |
| Person | name |
| Person | last_name |
| City | continent |
| City | country |
| City | name |
| City | Strength |

## Here is the desired output from the request

| Table name | Column name |
| --- | --- |
| Person | identification |
| Person | last_name |
| City | continent |

I'm using Oracle DMBS.
Thank you for your time

Comment: how do city and peson relate, there should be a column that points to the city

Comment: In this case there is no need for a connection between each other. Since all I'm looking for is the name of the columns

Comment: @nbk I don't think relationship of data has any importance here. OP just wants to return rows from this table with these two columns that fit their requirements (2 or more vowels, greater than 8 characters)

Comment: `Translate()` and `replace()` may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions used:

- [Translate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm)  alter characters from text to text identified
- [Replace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) substitute value in string from one value to another.
- [Length](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm) counts characters in string.

Notes:

- Since you indicated regular expressions may not be able to be used...
- we use translate to remove all the vowels setting them to special character "~"  Though I suppose we could have just used space ' '.
- Translate can't be to an empty string but replace can be.
- "Special" character "~" in the translate so if a column name has one of those this can result in an incorrect result to bypass the limit of it can't be blank.
- replace to eliminate the speical character.
- length's to ensure we removed at least 1 vowel.
- Included column "Z" to show you what the translate & replace are doing.
- not ideal in terms of performance because of the inability to use indexes owing to the fact we are using functions on data and limiting by that altered data.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d1de4d1344a3a5bacd11b126038f8d34) Pay attention to the comments for a simpler solution which avoids replace by including ~ in the translate.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'Person' "Table name", 'identification' "Column name" from dual union all
SELECT 'Person','name' from dual union all
SELECT 'Person','last_name' from dual union all
SELECT 'City','continent' from dual union all
SELECT 'City','country' from dual union all
SELECT 'City','name' from dual union all
SELECT 'City','Strength' from dual)

SELECT "Table name", "Column name", replace(translate("Column name",'aeiou','~'),'~','') z
FROM CTE
WHERE length("Column name")-length(replace(translate("Column name",'aeiou','~'),'~',''))>=2
  and length("Column name")>8
```

Giving us:

```
+------------+----------------+---------+
| Table name |  Column name   |    Z    |
+------------+----------------+---------+
| Person     | identification | dntfctn |
| Person     | last_name      | lst_nm  |
| City       | continent      | cntnnt  |
+------------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Again, I'm using ~ as a special character if any column name has it as a value that record would be returned inaccuratly.

Comment: Thank you this seems to work exactly as I wanted

Comment: @JuanAndresMendez You can simplify the query and get rid of the problem with `~` like by using `TRANSLATE(column_name, '~aeiou', '~')` and not bothering with the `REPLACE` function [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dade0d00fc5b0ea8ea47f32c592849c8)

Comment: @MT0 ok, I gotta admit, That's pretty cool.  Even if a records fields value contains a ~ it's not touched.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the regex could be a bit more elegant, but something like the following would get you in the ballpark:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE regexp_like(ColumnName, '^.*[aeiou]+.*[aeiou]+.*$', 'i') and LENGTH(ColumnName) > 8
```

Comment: I didn't know how to use regrexp_like this seems a great example thank you!

Comment: The regular expression can be much simpler as there is no need to match the entire string. Such as `[aeiou].*?[aeiou]` (which is a vowel and then zero-or-more characters until the next vowel is found).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way: compare the length of the word to the length of the word after the vowels are removed.

```sql
with data as (   
  select 'outLOOK' as word from dual union all    
  select 'today' as word from dual union all    
  select 'help' as word from dual    
)   
  SELECT  word
FROM    data
WHERE    LENGTH (word)
      - NVL ( LENGTH ( TRANSLATE ( word
                           , 'xAEIOUaeiou'
                 , 'x'
                 )
             )
        , 0
        ) >= 2
;
```

Or

```sql
with data as (   
  select 'outLOOK' as word from dual union all    
  select 'today' as word from dual union all    
  select 'help' as word from dual    
)   
SELECT  word
FROM    data
WHERE    REGEXP_LIKE ( word
            , '[AEIOUaeiou].*[AEIOUaeiou]'
            );
```

This searches for

- a vowel
- any number of characters, 0 or more
- another vowel.